# SwiftyJSON object with Alamofire post parameter

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

ok. Stuck on simple task, converting a project from AFNetworking swift 2 to Alamofire swift 3.

I have one json object (SwiftyJSON) and need to send as body json parameter.

Here is my object:

```
{
  "enableSMS" : 1,
  "deviceAssociationID" : 12,
  "timeStamp" : "2016-10-07 23:35:32",
  "userDeviceAccessID" : 1,
  "valueBattery" : 25,
  "deviceDescription" : "<null>",
  "deviceID" : 1,
  "valueTemperature" : 46,
  "valueTRange1" : "0.000000",
  "deviceTypeId" : 1,
  "latitude" : "-23.504236000000000",
  "enableEmail" : 1,
  "valueTiers" : [
    {
      "userShareDeviceId" : 6,
      "sharedStatusId" : 1,
      "sharedStatus" : "INVITE_SENT",
      "destUserId" : 60,
      "personEmail" : "eu@you.com",
      "sharedDate" : "2016-08-17 20:57:06",
      "personName" : "Daniel",
      "personPhone" : "+55 11 9999999999",
      "acceptationDate" : null
    },
    {
      "userShareDeviceId" : 7,
      "sharedStatusId" : 1,
      "sharedStatus" : "INVITE_SENT",
      "destUserId" : 1,
      "personEmail" : "x@y.com",
      "sharedDate" : "2016-10-04 20:00:06",
      "personName" : "John",
      "personPhone" : "",
      "acceptationDate" : null
    }
  ],
  "enableTimeRange" : 1,
  "deviceVersion" : "0.1",
  "valueSMS" : [
    {
      "SMSId" : 1,
      "personName" : "Daniel",
      "personPhone" : "+55 11 999999999"
    }
  ],
  "deviceName" : "Vovózinhaaaa",
  "jsonAddress" : "{\"place_id\":\"24020287\",\"licence\":\"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\\\/\\\/www.openstreetmap.org\\\/copyright\",\"osm_type\":\"node\",\"osm_id\":\"2355070909\",\"lat\":\"-23.5038297\",\"lon\":\"-46.6285165\",\"display_name\":\"Itaú Personalité, Avenida Brás Leme, Jardim São Bento, Casa Verde, SP, Microrregião de São Paulo, RMSP, Mesorregião Metropolitana de São Paulo, SP, Região Sudeste, 02022-010, Brasil\",\"address\":{\"bank\":\"Itaú Personalité\",\"road\":\"Avenida Brás Leme\",\"neighbourhood\":\"Jardim São Bento\",\"suburb\":\"Casa Verde\",\"city_district\":\"Casa Verde\",\"city\":\"SP\",\"county\":\"Microrregião de São Paulo\",\"state_district\":\"Mesorregião Metropolitana de São Paulo\",\"state\":\"SP\",\"postcode\":\"02022-010\",\"country\":\"Brasil\",\"country_code\":\"br\"},\"boundingbox\":[\"-23.5039297\",\"-23.5037297\",\"-46.6286165\",\"-46.6284165\"]}",
  "deviceJSONWeather" : "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-46.63,\"lat\":-23.47},\"weather\":[{\"id\":802,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"scattered clouds\",\"icon\":\"03n\"}],\"base\":\"cmc stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":299.26,\"pressure\":1023,\"humidity\":81,\"temp_min\":299.26,\"temp_max\":299.26},\"wind\":{\"speed\":3.08,\"deg\":70,\"gust\":3.08},\"rain\":{\"3h\":0.03},\"clouds\":{\"all\":36},\"dt\":1470863106,\"sys\":{\"type\":3,\"id\":135121,\"message\":0.0091,\"country\":\"BR\",\"sunrise\":1470821690,\"sunset\":1470862123},\"id\":3467431,\"name\":\"Cantareira\",\"cod\":200}",
  "acceleration" : "3.89743600",
  "temperature" : "27.00",
  "speed" : "9.000000",
  "valueEmails" : [
    {
      "emailId" : 1,
      "personName" : "John Doe",
      "personEmail" : "j@doe.com"
    },
    {
      "emailId" : 2,
      "personName" : "Daniel",
      "personEmail" : "eu@you.com"
    }
  ],
  "longitude" : "-46.628792000000000",
  "valueGeoFencing" : [
    {
      "geoFencingAnalyseSaturday" : 1,
      "geoFencingLongitude" : "-46.639857300000020",
      "geoFencingName" : "Geo 1",
      "geoFencingAddress" : "Tv. Heliodora, 14",
      "geoFencingLatitude" : "-23.503186700000000",
      "geoFencingTimeRange1" : "0.150000000",
      "geoFencingAnalyseSunday" : 0,
      "geoFencingTimeEnabled" : 0,
      "geoFencingAnalyseMonday" : 1,
      "geoFencingAnalyseTuesday" : 1,
      "geoFencingTypeId" : 1,
      "geoFencingTimeRange2" : "0.750000000",
      "geoFencingId" : 5,
      "geoFencingAnalyseFriday" : 1,
      "geoFencingRadius" : 744,
      "geoFencingAnalyseWednesday" : 0,
      "geoFencingTypeName" : "ENTER",
      "geoFencingAnalyseThursday" : 1
    }
  ],
  "enableImpact" : 1,
  "enableGeoFencing" : 1,
  "devicePicture" : "https:\/\/pic.com\/devices\/12.jpg",
  "userID" : 1,
  "enableAlerts" : 1,
  "useTypeDescription" : "SENIOR",
  "enableBattery" : 1,
  "valueSpeed" : 62,
  "batteryLevel" : 73,
  "valueTRange2" : "1.000000",
  "altitude" : "721.900024",
  "enableSpeed" : 1,
  "deviceTimeZoneName" : "(GMT -3:00) Eastern Brazil",
  "heading_to" : "116.839996",
  "enableTemperature" : 1,
  "enableTiers" : 1,
  "deviceStatus" : "ACTIVATED",
  "deviceSerialNumber" : "TRX00001",
  "alertsNonRead" : 69,
  "deviceUseTypeId" : 4,
  "deviceTimeZone" : "America\/Sao_Paulo"
}
```

Trying to post it directly (casting to Parameter type) my API doesn't recognize any parameter.

Then I converted to a dictionary:

```
do {
    let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
    userDevices.updateUserDevices(settings: dic as! Parameters) { (response, error) in
        print(response)
        print(error)
    }
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

Debugging Alamofire post I have this serialization:

```
"{\"enableSMS\":1,\"deviceAssociationID\":12,\"deviceTimeZone\":\"America\/Sao_Paulo\",\"userDeviceAccessID\":1,\"valueBattery\":25,\"deviceDescription\":\"<null>\",\"deviceID\":1,\"valueTemperature\":46,\"valueTRange1\":\"0.000000\",\"deviceTypeId\":1,\"latitude\":\"-23.504236000000000\",\"enableEmail\":1,\"valueTiers\":[{\"userShareDeviceId\":6,\"sharedStatusId\":1,\"sharedStatus\":\"INVITE_SENT\",\"destUserId\":60,\"personEmail\":\"eu@daniellombardi.com.br\",\"sharedDate\":\"2016-08-17 20:57:06\",\"personName\":\"Daniel Lombardi\",\"personPhone\":\"+55 11 981378213\",\"acceptationDate\":null},{\"userShareDeviceId\":7,\"sharedStatusId\":1,\"sharedStatus\":\"INVITE_SENT\",\"destUserId\":1,\"personEmail\":\"giulio@loffreda.com.br\",\"sharedDate\":\"2016-10-04 20:00:06\",\"personName\":\"Giulio\",\"personPhone\":\"\",\"acceptationDate\":null}],\"enableTimeRange\":1,\"deviceVersion\":\"0.1\",\"valueSMS\":[{\"SMSId\":1,\"personName\":\"Daniel Lombardi\",\"personPhone\":\"+55 11 981378213\"}],\"deviceName\":\"Vovózinhaaaa\",\"userID\":1,\"deviceJSONWeather\":\"{\\\"coord\\\":{\\\"lon\\\":-46.63,\\\"lat\\\":-23.47},\\\"weather\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":802,\\\"main\\\":\\\"Clouds\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"scattered clouds\\\",\\\"icon\\\":\\\"03n\\\"}],\\\"base\\\":\\\"cmc stations\\\",\\\"main\\\":{\\\"temp\\\":299.26,\\\"pressure\\\":1023,\\\"humidity\\\":81,\\\"temp_min\\\":299.26,\\\"temp_max\\\":299.26},\\\"wind\\\":{\\\"speed\\\":3.08,\\\"deg\\\":70,\\\"gust\\\":3.08},\\\"rain\\\":{\\\"3h\\\":0.03},\\\"clouds\\\":{\\\"all\\\":36},\\\"dt\\\":1470863106,\\\"sys\\\":{\\\"type\\\":3,\\\"id\\\":135121,\\\"message\\\":0.0091,\\\"country\\\":\\\"BR\\\",\\\"sunrise\\\":1470821690,\\\"sunset\\\":1470862123},\\\"id\\\":3467431,\\\"name\\\":\\\"Cantareira\\\",\\\"cod\\\":200}\",\"jsonAddress\":\"{\\\"place_id\\\":\\\"24020287\\\",\\\"licence\\\":\\\"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\\\/\\\/www.openstreetmap.org\\\/copyright\\\",\\\"osm_type\\\":\\\"node\\\",\\\"osm_id\\\":\\\"2355070909\\\",\\\"lat\\\":\\\"-23.5038297\\\",\\\"lon\\\":\\\"-46.6285165\\\",\\\"display_name\\\":\\\"Itaú Personalité, Avenida Brás Leme, Jardim São Bento, Casa Verde, SP, Microrregião de São Paulo, RMSP, Mesorregião Metropolitana de São Paulo, SP, Região Sudeste, 02022-010, Brasil\\\",\\\"address\\\":{\\\"bank\\\":\\\"Itaú Personalité\\\",\\\"road\\\":\\\"Avenida Brás Leme\\\",\\\"neighbourhood\\\":\\\"Jardim São Bento\\\",\\\"suburb\\\":\\\"Casa Verde\\\",\\\"city_district\\\":\\\"Casa Verde\\\",\\\"city\\\":\\\"SP\\\",\\\"county\\\":\\\"Microrregião de São Paulo\\\",\\\"state_district\\\":\\\"Mesorregião Metropolitana de São Paulo\\\",\\\"state\\\":\\\"SP\\\",\\\"postcode\\\":\\\"02022-010\\\",\\\"country\\\":\\\"Brasil\\\",\\\"country_code\\\":\\\"br\\\"},\\\"boundingbox\\\":[\\\"-23.5039297\\\",\\\"-23.5037297\\\",\\\"-46.6286165\\\",\\\"-46.6284165\\\"]}\",\"temperature\":\"27.00\",\"speed\":\"9.000000\",\"valueEmails\":[{\"emailId\":1,\"personName\":\"Giulio Loffreda\",\"personEmail\":\"giulio@loffreda.com.br\"},{\"emailId\":2,\"personName\":\"Daniel Lombardi\",\"personEmail\":\"eu@daniellombardi.com.br\"}],\"longitude\":\"-46.628792000000000\",\"valueGeoFencing\":[{\"geoFencingAnalyseThursday\":1,\"geoFencingLongitude\":\"-46.639857300000020\",\"geoFencingName\":\"Geo 1\",\"geoFencingAddress\":\"Tv. Heliodora, 14\",\"geoFencingLatitude\":\"-23.503186700000000\",\"geoFencingTimeRange1\":\"0.150000000\",\"geoFencingAnalyseSunday\":0,\"geoFencingTimeEnabled\":0,\"geoFencingAnalyseMonday\":1,\"geoFencingAnalyseTuesday\":1,\"geoFencingTypeId\":1,\"geoFencingTimeRange2\":\"0.750000000\",\"geoFencingId\":5,\"geoFencingAnalyseFriday\":1,\"geoFencingRadius\":744,\"geoFencingAnalyseSaturday\":1,\"geoFencingAnalyseWednesday\":0,\"geoFencingTypeName\":\"ENTER\"}],\"enableImpact\":1,\"enableGeoFencing\":1,\"devicePicture\":\"https:\/\/profiles.t-rex.io\/devices\/12.jpg\",\"acceleration\":\"3.89743600\",\"enableAlerts\":1,\"useTypeDescription\":\"SENIOR\",\"enableBattery\":1,\"valueSpeed\":62,\"batteryLevel\":73,\"valueTRange2\":\"1.000000\",\"altitude\":\"721.900024\",\"enableSpeed\":1,\"deviceTimeZoneName\":\"(GMT -3:00) Eastern Brazil\",\"heading_to\":\"116.839996\",\"enableTemperature\":1,\"enableTiers\":1,\"deviceStatus\":\"ACTIVATED\",\"deviceSerialNumber\":\"TRX00001\",\"alertsNonRead\":69,\"deviceUseTypeId\":4,\"timeStamp\":\"2016-10-07 23:35:32\"}" \
```

Which is not json or api conform.

This is my call:

```
alamoFireManager?.request("\(urlUserApi)\", method: .post, parameters: settings, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:["Authorization" : userData.apiKey])
            .debugLog()
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    let useType = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    if ((useType["error"].bool) == true) {
                        let error = NSError(domain: UserErrorDomain, code: -982, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: translateStrings(useType["message"].string!)])
                        completion(nil, error)
                    } else {
                        completion(useType, nil)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            })
```

Trying to change the encoding (tried all of them) with URLEncoding.default I have this:

```
"acceleration=3.89743600&alertsNonRead=69&altitude=721.900024&batteryLevel=73&deviceAssociationID=12&deviceDescription=%3Cnull%3E&deviceID=1&deviceJSONWeather=%7B%22coord%22%3A%7B%22lon%22%3A-46.63%2C%22lat%22%3A-23.47%7D%2C%22weather%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A802%2C%22main%22%3A%22Clouds%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22scattered%20clouds%22%2C%22icon%22%3A%2203n%22%7D%5D%2C%22base%22%3A%22cmc%20stations%22%2C%22main%22%3A%7B%22temp%22%3A299.26%2C%22pressure%22%3A1023%2C%22humidity%22%3A81%2C%22temp_min%22%3A299.26%2C%22temp_max%22%3A299.26%7D%2C%22wind%22%3A%7B%22speed%22%3A3.08%2C%22deg%22%3A70%2C%22gust%22%3A3.08%7D%2C%22rain%22%3A%7B%223h%22%3A0.03%7D%2C%22clouds%22%3A%7B%22all%22%3A36%7D%2C%22dt%22%3A1470863106%2C%22sys%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A3%2C%22id%22%3A135121%2C%22message%22%3A0.0091%2C%22country%22%3A%22BR%22%2C%22sunrise%22%3A1470821690%2C%22sunset%22%3A1470862123%7D%2C%22id%22%3A3467431%2C%22name%22%3A%22Cantareira%22%2C%22cod%22%3A200%7D&deviceName=Vov%C3%B3zinhaaaa&devicePicture=https%3A//profiles.t-rex.io/devices/12.jpg&deviceSerialNumber=TRX00001&deviceStatus=ACTIVATED&deviceTimeZone=America/Sao_Paulo&deviceTimeZoneName=%28GMT%20-3%3A00%29%20Eastern%20Brazil&deviceTypeId=1&deviceUseTypeId=4&deviceVersion=0.1&enableAlerts=1&enableBattery=1&enableEmail=1&enableGeoFencing=1&enableImpact=1&enableSMS=1&enableSpeed=1&enableTemperature=1&enableTiers=1&enableTimeRange=1&heading_to=116.839996&jsonAddress=%7B%22place_id%22%3A%2224020287%22%2C%22licence%22%3A%22Data%20%C2%A9%20OpenStreetMap%20contributors%2C%20ODbL%201.0.%20http%3A%5C/%5C/www.openstreetmap.org%5C/copyright%22%2C%22osm_type%22%3A%22node%22%2C%22osm_id%22%3A%222355070909%22%2C%22lat%22%3A%22-23.5038297%22%2C%22lon%22%3A%22-46.6285165%22%2C%22display_name%22%3A%22Ita%C3%BA%20Personalit%C3%A9%2C%20Avenida%20Br%C3%A1s%20Leme%2C%20Jardim%20S%C3%A3o%20Bento%2C%20Casa%20Verde%2C%20SP%2C%20Microrregi%C3%A3o%20de%20S%C3%A3o%20Paulo%2C%20RMSP%2C%20Mesorregi%C3%A3o%20Metropolitana%20de%20S%C3%A3o%20Paulo%2C%20SP%2C%20Regi%C3%A3o%20Sudeste%2C%2002022-010%2C%20Brasil%22%2C%22address%22%3A%7B%22bank%22%3A%22Ita%C3%BA%20Personalit%C3%A9%22%2C%22road%22%3A%22Avenida%20Br%C3%A1s%20Leme%22%2C%22neighbourhood%22%3A%22Jardim%20S%C3%A3o%20Bento%22%2C%22suburb%22%3A%22Casa%20Verde%22%2C%22city_district%22%3A%22Casa%20Verde%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22SP%22%2C%22county%22%3A%22Microrregi%C3%A3o%20de%20S%C3%A3o%20Paulo%22%2C%22state_district%22%3A%22Mesorregi%C3%A3o%20Metropolitana%20de%20S%C3%A3o%20Paulo%22%2C%22state%22%3A%22SP%22%2C%22postcode%22%3A%2202022-010%22%2C%22country%22%3A%22Brasil%22%2C%22country_code%22%3A%22br%22%7D%2C%22boundingbox%22%3A%5B%22-23.5039297%22%2C%22-23.5037297%22%2C%22-46.6286165%22%2C%22-46.6284165%22%5D%7D&latitude=-23.504236000000000&longitude=-46.628792000000000&speed=9.000000&temperature=27.00&timeStamp=2016-10-07%2023%3A35%3A32&useTypeDescription=SENIOR&userDeviceAccessID=1&userID=1&valueBattery=25&valueEmails%5B%5D%5BpersonName%5D=Giulio%20Loffreda&valueEmails%5B%5D%5BpersonEmail%5D=giulio%40loffreda.com.br&valueEmails%5B%5D%5BemailId%5D=1&valueEmails%5B%5D%5BpersonName%5D=Daniel%20Lombardi&valueEmails%5B%5D%5BpersonEmail%5D=eu%40daniellombardi.com.br&valueEmails%5B%5D%5BemailId%5D=2&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingTimeEnabled%5D=0&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingAnalyseFriday%5D=1&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingLongitude%5D=-46.639857300000020&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingAddress%5D=Tv.%20Heliodora%2C%2014&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingId%5D=5&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingAnalyseMonday%5D=1&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingAnalyseWednesday%5D=0&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingAnalyseThursday%5D=1&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingLatitude%5D=-23.503186700000000&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingAnalyseTuesday%5D=1&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingTypeId%5D=1&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingTypeName%5D=ENTER&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingTimeRange1%5D=0.150000000&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingName%5D=Geo%201&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingTimeRange2%5D=0.750000000&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingAnalyseSunday%5D=0&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingRadius%5D=744&valueGeoFencing%5B%5D%5BgeoFencingAnalyseSaturday%5D=1&valueSMS%5B%5D%5BpersonPhone%5D=%2B55%2011%20981378213&valueSMS%5B%5D%5BpersonName%5D=Daniel%20Lombardi&valueSMS%5B%5D%5BSMSId%5D=1&valueSpeed=62&valueTRange1=0.000000&valueTRange2=1.000000&valueTemperature=46&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BuserShareDeviceId%5D=6&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BacceptationDate%5D=%3Cnull%3E&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BsharedStatusId%5D=1&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BpersonPhone%5D=%2B55%2011%20981378213&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BpersonEmail%5D=eu%40daniellombardi.com.br&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BsharedStatus%5D=INVITE_SENT&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BsharedDate%5D=2016-08-17%2020%3A57%3A06&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BdestUserId%5D=60&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BpersonName%5D=Daniel%20Lombardi&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BuserShareDeviceId%5D=7&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BacceptationDate%5D=%3Cnull%3E&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BsharedStatusId%5D=1&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BpersonPhone%5D=&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BpersonEmail%5D=giulio%40loffreda.com.br&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BsharedStatus%5D=INVITE_SENT&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BsharedDate%5D=2016-10-04%2020%3A00%3A06&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BdestUserId%5D=1&valueTiers%5B%5D%5BpersonName%5D=Giulio" \
```

Which should be working, but since in this object I have subarrays my backend doesn't understand as json object.

The silly trick is that it was working with AFNetworking.

Am I missing any thing ? surely, but what ?
Already read all Alamofire and SwiftyJSON docs and tried many types of serialization.

**EDIT:**

**SOLUTION:**

At least in my case I changed some parameters and it worked like a charm:

```
alamoFireManager?.request("\(urlUserApi)\", method: .post, parameters: settings.dictionaryValue, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers:["Authorization" : userData.apiKey, "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"])
    .debugLog()
    .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let useType = JSON(response.result.value!)
            if ((useType["error"].bool) == true) {
                let error = NSError(domain: UserErrorDomain, code: -982, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: translateStrings(useType["message"].string!)])
                completion(nil, error)
            } else {
                completion(useType, nil)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    })
```

this did the trick:

```
"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

as well as changing the parameter type from Parameter to JSON:

```
settings: JSON
```

and implement it as dictionary:

```
settings.dictionaryValue
```

Hope it helps somebody

The answer by @zombie works fine, just didn't use it to not change my implementation standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be able to add your json as a string in swift i converted it with http://bernhardhaeussner.de/odd/json-escape/

so my code looks like this

```
let values = "{\n  \"enableSMS\" : 1,\n  \"deviceAssociationID\" : 12,\n  \"timeStamp\" : \"2016-10-07 23:35:32\",\n  \"userDeviceAccessID\" : 1,\n  \"valueBattery\" : 25,\n  \"deviceDescription\" : \"<null>\",\n  \"deviceID\" : 1,\n  \"valueTemperature\" : 46,\n  \"valueTRange1\" : \"0.000000\",\n  \"deviceTypeId\" : 1,\n  \"latitude\" : \"-23.504236000000000\",\n  \"enableEmail\" : 1,\n  \"valueTiers\" : [\n    {\n      \"userShareDeviceId\" : 6,\n      \"sharedStatusId\" : 1,\n      \"sharedStatus\" : \"INVITE_SENT\",\n      \"destUserId\" : 60,\n      \"personEmail\" : \"eu@you.com\",\n      \"sharedDate\" : \"2016-08-17 20:57:06\",\n      \"personName\" : \"Daniel\",\n      \"personPhone\" : \"+55 11 9999999999\",\n      \"acceptationDate\" : null\n    },\n    {\n      \"userShareDeviceId\" : 7,\n      \"sharedStatusId\" : 1,\n      \"sharedStatus\" : \"INVITE_SENT\",\n      \"destUserId\" : 1,\n      \"personEmail\" : \"x@y.com\",\n      \"sharedDate\" : \"2016-10-04 20:00:06\",\n      \"personName\" : \"John\",\n      \"personPhone\" : \"\",\n      \"acceptationDate\" : null\n    }\n  ],\n  \"enableTimeRange\" : 1,\n  \"deviceVersion\" : \"0.1\",\n  \"valueSMS\" : [\n    {\n      \"SMSId\" : 1,\n      \"personName\" : \"Daniel\",\n      \"personPhone\" : \"+55 11 999999999\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"deviceName\" : \"Vovózinhaaaa\",\n  \"jsonAddress\" : \"{\\\"place_id\\\":\\\"24020287\\\",\\\"licence\\\":\\\"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/www.openstreetmap.org\\\\\\/copyright\\\",\\\"osm_type\\\":\\\"node\\\",\\\"osm_id\\\":\\\"2355070909\\\",\\\"lat\\\":\\\"-23.5038297\\\",\\\"lon\\\":\\\"-46.6285165\\\",\\\"display_name\\\":\\\"Itaú Personalité, Avenida Brás Leme, Jardim São Bento, Casa Verde, SP, Microrregião de São Paulo, RMSP, Mesorregião Metropolitana de São Paulo, SP, Região Sudeste, 02022-010, Brasil\\\",\\\"address\\\":{\\\"bank\\\":\\\"Itaú Personalité\\\",\\\"road\\\":\\\"Avenida Brás Leme\\\",\\\"neighbourhood\\\":\\\"Jardim São Bento\\\",\\\"suburb\\\":\\\"Casa Verde\\\",\\\"city_district\\\":\\\"Casa Verde\\\",\\\"city\\\":\\\"SP\\\",\\\"county\\\":\\\"Microrregião de São Paulo\\\",\\\"state_district\\\":\\\"Mesorregião Metropolitana de São Paulo\\\",\\\"state\\\":\\\"SP\\\",\\\"postcode\\\":\\\"02022-010\\\",\\\"country\\\":\\\"Brasil\\\",\\\"country_code\\\":\\\"br\\\"},\\\"boundingbox\\\":[\\\"-23.5039297\\\",\\\"-23.5037297\\\",\\\"-46.6286165\\\",\\\"-46.6284165\\\"]}\",\n  \"deviceJSONWeather\" : \"{\\\"coord\\\":{\\\"lon\\\":-46.63,\\\"lat\\\":-23.47},\\\"weather\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":802,\\\"main\\\":\\\"Clouds\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"scattered clouds\\\",\\\"icon\\\":\\\"03n\\\"}],\\\"base\\\":\\\"cmc stations\\\",\\\"main\\\":{\\\"temp\\\":299.26,\\\"pressure\\\":1023,\\\"humidity\\\":81,\\\"temp_min\\\":299.26,\\\"temp_max\\\":299.26},\\\"wind\\\":{\\\"speed\\\":3.08,\\\"deg\\\":70,\\\"gust\\\":3.08},\\\"rain\\\":{\\\"3h\\\":0.03},\\\"clouds\\\":{\\\"all\\\":36},\\\"dt\\\":1470863106,\\\"sys\\\":{\\\"type\\\":3,\\\"id\\\":135121,\\\"message\\\":0.0091,\\\"country\\\":\\\"BR\\\",\\\"sunrise\\\":1470821690,\\\"sunset\\\":1470862123},\\\"id\\\":3467431,\\\"name\\\":\\\"Cantareira\\\",\\\"cod\\\":200}\",\n  \"acceleration\" : \"3.89743600\",\n  \"temperature\" : \"27.00\",\n  \"speed\" : \"9.000000\",\n  \"valueEmails\" : [\n    {\n      \"emailId\" : 1,\n      \"personName\" : \"John Doe\",\n      \"personEmail\" : \"j@doe.com\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"emailId\" : 2,\n      \"personName\" : \"Daniel\",\n      \"personEmail\" : \"eu@you.com\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"longitude\" : \"-46.628792000000000\",\n  \"valueGeoFencing\" : [\n    {\n      \"geoFencingAnalyseSaturday\" : 1,\n      \"geoFencingLongitude\" : \"-46.639857300000020\",\n      \"geoFencingName\" : \"Geo 1\",\n      \"geoFencingAddress\" : \"Tv. Heliodora, 14\",\n      \"geoFencingLatitude\" : \"-23.503186700000000\",\n      \"geoFencingTimeRange1\" : \"0.150000000\",\n      \"geoFencingAnalyseSunday\" : 0,\n      \"geoFencingTimeEnabled\" : 0,\n      \"geoFencingAnalyseMonday\" : 1,\n      \"geoFencingAnalyseTuesday\" : 1,\n      \"geoFencingTypeId\" : 1,\n      \"geoFencingTimeRange2\" : \"0.750000000\",\n      \"geoFencingId\" : 5,\n      \"geoFencingAnalyseFriday\" : 1,\n      \"geoFencingRadius\" : 744,\n      \"geoFencingAnalyseWednesday\" : 0,\n      \"geoFencingTypeName\" : \"ENTER\",\n      \"geoFencingAnalyseThursday\" : 1\n    }\n  ],\n  \"enableImpact\" : 1,\n  \"enableGeoFencing\" : 1,\n  \"devicePicture\" : \"https:\\/\\/pic.com\\/devices\\/12.jpg\",\n  \"userID\" : 1,\n  \"enableAlerts\" : 1,\n  \"useTypeDescription\" : \"SENIOR\",\n  \"enableBattery\" : 1,\n  \"valueSpeed\" : 62,\n  \"batteryLevel\" : 73,\n  \"valueTRange2\" : \"1.000000\",\n  \"altitude\" : \"721.900024\",\n  \"enableSpeed\" : 1,\n  \"deviceTimeZoneName\" : \"(GMT -3:00) Eastern Brazil\",\n  \"heading_to\" : \"116.839996\",\n  \"enableTemperature\" : 1,\n  \"enableTiers\" : 1,\n  \"deviceStatus\" : \"ACTIVATED\",\n  \"deviceSerialNumber\" : \"TRX00001\",\n  \"alertsNonRead\" : 69,\n  \"deviceUseTypeId\" : 4,\n  \"deviceTimeZone\" : \"America\\/Sao_Paulo\"\n}"


      var data = values.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

      do {
         var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])

         print(json)

         var request = URLRequest(url: url)
       request.httpMethod = "POST"
       request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

       request.httpBody = json

       Alamofire.request(request)
           .responseJSON { response in

               switch response.result {
               case .failure(let error):
                   print(error)

                   if let data = response.data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                       print(responseString)
                   }
               case .success(let responseObject):
                   print(responseObject)
               }
       }
      }
      catch {
         print(error)
      }
```

Comment: having hard time to figure out why my object isn't a valid json. Using http://jsonlint.com/ I get a valid json. This line try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values) crashes my app with Invalid top-level type in JSON write. Testing with if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(settings) {} invalidate my object which is exactly the same json in my question.

Comment: it worked and your code gave me a valuable tip... changed my method and worked like a charm. Will edit my question and put the solution (as I implemented) but your code works fine. Thank you so much for your help